# How to use a recipe to deal with PPA package dependency change across distribution

Tags: ppa, recipe

I am using a recipe to keep a program packaged in my ppa.  From Oneiric onwards it seems that some of the dependency locations have changed.  specifically the libQtCore.so (and a couple other QT libs).  All the legacy versions of the application build but Oneiric and Precise have failed to build from the old recipe.  I can deal with this locally because I can change the library location in the rules file.

I was wondering how best to deal with this in my ppa.  Should I have a separate debian file in its own repo that is specific for the release, get the recipe to pull the debian file and merge when its time to build?  Then have separate recipe for each distro?

Or can I deal with this in the recipe directly.

Or is there a better way that I haven't thought of.

Thanks

Comment: What's a recipe?

Comment: @enzotib Look [here](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds/Recipes).

Answer (score 1):

Technically you could add a `run` line to your recipe to execute some script that performs the substitution in the `debian/rules` file depending on the target distribution. However, that would work only when running `bzr build` locally because `run` isn't supported in launchpad as noted [here](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds/BzrBuilder#Running_commands_in_recipes) (I guess that's because of security concerns).

Hence, my advice is to have two different recipes pointing to different branches for the packaging files and launch each recipe for the appropriate distributions.